# Error: "The method show() from the type Window is deprecated" 

Tags: java, deprecated

this is a simple program to just open an AWT. Im using eclipse and i get the error shown above for frame.show(); Eclipse is crossing "show" with a line. All i want this program to do is just display a 300px by 300px frame window. Heres the full code:

```
    Frame frame = new Frame("Hello World");
    // ...        
    frame.show();
```

Comment: You can always do `javac -Xlint Myprogram.java` but follow Ernest response.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The method `show()` is, indeed, deprecated. *Deprecated* means that you're not supposed to use it anymore, as it's been replaced by something better and may be removed in the future. In this case, you're supposed to use `setVisible(true)` instead.

If you go and look at the Javadoc for a deprecated method, it will generally tell you what the intended replacement is.

Comment: +1, also by default this is just a warning but it looks like the OP's preferences are set to treat this as an error.

Comment: Ernest why did you change the code i set above? What was the point and thanks for your input but where do i define it?

Comment: I removed 99% of the code because it didn't matter for the problem here; the problem is just "Eclipse marks the method Frame.show() as deprecated", and none of the other code had anything to do with that. Anyway, you just replace "frame.show()" with "frame.setVisible(true)".

Comment: Well thanks but even after fixing that problem i still get an error when i run it in eclipse.  #
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (classFileParser.cpp:3174), pid=21280, tid=18000
#  Error: ShouldNotReachHere()

Comment: Wow, that looks like a JVM bug. You probably want to open a new question for that one. But first just cleaning/rebuilding the project, and/or restarting Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You now have to use setVisible(true) instead.

Answer (score -1):

The method show() is deprecated means it's no longer supported and not usable.
it is not good for future. we must replace .show() to setVisible(true).
if we can't change now that was effect in future.
so change that.
i hope my answer is useful for all you guys.....
Thank You From Umang Paneri.

Comment: and this adds what to the answers that were already written in 2012 by kenneth and Ernest?